# Autenticación Firebase y Google Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-auth

Tengo una app en Android Studio con java. Quiero poner una autenticación para entrar y cuando accedo con el boton de Google funciona sin ningún problema, pero cuando quiero acceder de manera anónima con el botón de Anonimo, ma aparece este error:

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignUp are blocked. ]

En Firebase tengo habilitada la autenticación anónima y en Google Console tengo habilitada la API Identity Toolkit, pero no consigo eliminar el error.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

He probado añadiendo más permisos a las cuentas de servicio de Google Console, pero sigue igual.
El código en teoría está bien, por lo que el problema es del acceso.
Ya tengo otras conexiones en esa misma app con Firebase y funciona bien.